# Combining two tables in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. How can I get the output as provided?

**tbl_Configure**

```
Date        Name
1/1/13      Sandeep
1/2/13      Sudeep
```

**tbl_Install**

```
Date        Name
1/1/13      Sandeep
1/2/13      Sandeep
```

Output:

```
Date        Name        Type
1/1/13      Sandeep     Configure
1/1/13      Sandeep     Install
1/2/13      Sudeep      Configure
1/2/13      Sandeep     Install
```

Comment: from where you are taking the column "Type"

Comment: @Suganthan If I'm guessing correctly, it looks like it is from the table's name

Comment: @Suganthan The 'type' column is like an indicator of the row as answered by Pepe below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select config.Date, config.Name, 'Configure' as Type From tbl_Configure config
Union
Select install.Date, install.Name, 'Install' as Type From tbl_Install install
```